# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created a `AbstractUser` class in `my reg_group` app's `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import escape, mark_safe


class User(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True, null=True)


class User_Info(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

I also have another app `notification` whose `models.py` is such:

```
from django.db import models
from swampdragon.models import SelfPublishModel
from .serializers import NotificationSerializer


class Notification(SelfPublishModel, models.Model):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer
    message = models.TextField()
```

When i run `python manage.py runserver` i get the error

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'email' in class 'User' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'AbstractUser'

But there is no `email` field in `notification` database.

The raw code of database is such :

```
CREATE TABLE "notifications_notification" (
    "id"    integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "level" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    "actor_object_id"   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "verb"  varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "description"   text,
    "target_object_id"  varchar(255),
    "action_object_object_id"   varchar(255),
    "timestamp" datetime NOT NULL,
    "public"    bool NOT NULL,
    "action_object_content_type_id" integer,
    "actor_content_type_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "recipient_id"  integer NOT NULL,
    "target_content_type_id"    integer,
    "deleted"   bool NOT NULL,
    "emailed"   bool NOT NULL,
    "data"  text,
    "unread"    bool NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("recipient_id") REFERENCES "reg_group_user"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    FOREIGN KEY("target_content_type_id") REFERENCES "django_content_type"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    FOREIGN KEY("actor_content_type_id") REFERENCES "django_content_type"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    FOREIGN KEY("action_object_content_type_id") REFERENCES "django_content_type"("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

This was of course, `auto-generated`.

I'm not understanding why I'm getting a clash in fields error when there is no such common field?

Comment: Ist the common field “email” also defined in abstractUser or its parents? That’s literally what the error is telling you

Comment: how is it a common field

Comment: it is not present in `notification.model`

Comment: Not your notification model. You are inheriting from AbstractUser which already has an email field

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with notification. The error is in User which is redefining the email field it inherits from Abstract user.

Comment: it was working perfectly fine until i created `notification` app :/

Comment: Well have you tried removing the notification again and trying again?

Comment: The thing is the notification model does not even reference the user model, so its hard to believe that it worked before

Comment: i reinstalled `django` and now it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have an `Email` field on your `User` Model because it is already present in `AbstractUser`.
So just change this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, default=None, blank=True, null=True)
```

To this:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_agency = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_vendor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And you can continue using `Email` field because it is contained in `AbstractUser`.

For other info see [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)

Comment: So how basically can you override it? for example, I have `is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)` but the default for Django is False. who do I force it to be `True` for the subclass?